# Heroku application error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served (django)

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, heroku

Hi i am newbee in heroku and stuck in process of deploying heroku application and i am not able to track where is the error so please help me out , using python django for application :-
after running `heroku log`

> (fdttest) abhisek@jarvis:~/Desktop/testenvFDT/foodmood$ heroku logs
>   2018-12-12T19:49:28.330386+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user
>   raizadaabhi11@gmail.com 2018-12-12T19:49:28.330386+00:00 app[api]:
>   Release v1 created by user raizadaabhi11@gmail.com
>   2018-12-12T19:49:30.426621+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user
>   raizadaabhi11@gmail.com 2018-12-12T19:49:30.426621+00:00 app[api]:
>   Release v2 created by user raizadaabhi11@gmail.com
>   2018-12-12T21:10:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
>   raizadaabhi11@gmail.com 2018-12-12T21:10:52.000000+00:00 app[api]:
>   Build failed -- check your build logs 2018-12-12T21:15:18.000000+00:00
>   app[api]: Build started by user raizadaabhi11@gmail.com
>   2018-12-12T21:15:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your
>   build logs 2018-12-12T21:21:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by
>   user raizadaabhi11@gmail.com 2018-12-12T21:21:22.000000+00:00
>   app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
>   2018-12-12T21:24:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
>   raizadaabhi11@gmail.com 2018-12-12T21:25:21.659682+00:00 app[api]:
>   Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-flexible-33726) by user
>   raizadaabhi11@ gmail.com

The `Procfile` contain :-
web: gunicorn foodmood.wsgi --log-file -

Comment: What is your build logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your Procfile to just:

```
web: gunicorn foodmood.wsgi
```

I think for some reason including --log-file- screws up the build with gunicorn.

Comment: it still showing the same error

Comment: Hey thanks it worked adding to it :--In new update of WhiteNoise "'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'," need to added in setting .py at MIDDLEWARE just below security middleware as well as in wsgi.py every thing related to white Noise should be remover